# Visual Studio: 'using namespace' not being recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have a Selenium framework that has been smooth sailing ever since it's creation. I implemented the Visual Studio Team Explorer today and after pulling from my remote branch, Intellisense started yelling at me, saying that one of my namespaces does not exist. The lines that it doesn't like are

```
using PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Maintenance;
```

and

```
var SettlementAccountReconciliations = new SettlementAccountReconciliation(_driver);
```

The SettlementAccountReconciliation is found within the Maintenance directory. Here is my full code for the test class where it does not like the directory:

```
using NLog.Internal;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using PageObjectModel.ControlObjects;
using PageObjectModel.PageObjects;
using PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Process;
using PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Status;
using System;
using PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Maintenance; // **LINE WITH MAINTENANCE UNDERLINED**


namespace PageObjectModel.Tests.TaskTesting
{
    [TestFixture]
    class JiraTaskTesting
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver();
            DriverContext.Driver = _driver;

            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            var ConfigManager = new ConfigurationManager();
            var Login = new Login(_driver);
            Login.SignIn(ConfigManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ReportNameStandardizationSettlementAccountReconciliations()
        {
            // **LINE WITH UNDERLINE**
            var SettlementAccountReconciliations = new SettlementAccountReconciliation(_driver);
            var Utilities = new Utilities(_driver);
            var ReportPopup = SettlementAccountReconciliations.ExportReconciliationReport();
            ReportPopup.StartDate.SetValue(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            ReportPopup.EndDate.SetValue(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            ReportPopup.ExportButton.Click();
            Assert.IsTrue(Utilities.ValidateFilePresent("Settlement Account Reconciliation"));
            Utilities.DeleteFile("Settlement Account Reconciliation");
        }
```

Also, here is the SettlementAccountReconciliation found within the Maintenance namespace:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Maintenance
{
    public class SettlementAccountReconciliation
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

        public SettlementAccountReconciliation(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
            var Utilities = new Utilities(driver);
            string TradingUrl = Utilities.RefactorUrl("/SettlementAccountReconciliation");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(TradingUrl);
            WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            try
            {
                Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//a[text()='Settlement Account Reconciliations']")));
                Console.WriteLine("SettlementAccountReconciliation Page Label Found");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SettlementAccountReconciliation Page Label Not Found, timing out");
            }
        }
```

This is an image of what is shown in my test class for the Directives:
[image: Error 1]

And for the SettlementAccountReconciliation constructor:
[image]

I have all of my code in the Page Object Model format, and this is how my file structure is lined out:[image: File Structure]

I know this question is long winded but to continue, the tests run just fine, and the solution builds like a charm. I just need to figure out how to get the text editor to not think there are issues with my code.

Visual Studio tells me that "The type or namespace name 'Maintenance' does not exist in the namespace PageObjectModel.PageObjects'", but it does.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT:

I fixed it.

I don't why it worked, but it did.

All I did was renamed the Maintenance folder to Maintenance1, recreated the Maintenance folder, and dragged and dropped the SettlementAccountReconciliation class into the Maintenance folder.

I am guessing there was some random property or setting stored in a temp folder somewhere in Timbuktu that was stored for the existing folder that was reset or deleted when the new folder was created.

Thanks to everyone who put time into helping me out!

Comment: Do you use resharper? Also, what version of VS2017 are you on?

Comment: Check if you have errors in compiling the project and files that defines the PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Maintenance namespace.

Comment: have you tried restoring your nuget packages?

Comment: Have you turned Visual Studio on and off again? (restarted, only slightly joking- sometimes the editor messes up)

Comment: @JohnKoerner - I use ReSharper, and I am on v 15.4.1

Comment: @JoshuaMiller - I have rebooted VS and my full machine as well

Comment: @Steve - I have no compilation errors and all files are straight forward

Comment: @NicoRiff - I cleared the cache and refreshed all nuget packages

Comment: @JonahOberloh In the bottom right corner of the IDE, see if there is a notification from resharper (might just be a yellow exclamation point icon) indicating it had trouble loading refs.  Sometimes just clicking on that will reload things and fix it.

Comment: @JohnKoerner There was not any indicator of a problem, but I right clicked the ReSharper icon and did a solution wide analysis. It showed up as a green check mark, and I still have the same error in the files referencing the SettlementAccountReconciliation.cs through using PageObjectModel.PageObjects.Maintenance;.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Resharper installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the Maintenance folder to Maintenance1, recreated the Maintenance folder, and dragged and dropped the SettlementAccountReconciliation class into the Maintenance folder, and it seems to have fixed the issue.

I am guessing there was some random property or setting stored in a temp folder somewhere in Timbuktu that was stored for the existing folder that was reset or deleted when the new folder was created.

Comment: Usually when doing something like this fixes it it was likely that your .cs file was not set to `Compile` for the build action

Comment: Actually I'm positive that the cs file was set to Compile, interestingly enough that was one of the first things I checked when doing some of my own research before posting the question.

Comment: 5.5 years later and still relevant. I just had the same thing happen in a .NET Core 6 project (referencing a namespace within the same project) and this resolved it. Thanks @JOberloh

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before myself. Check the file and folder names in your project directory, the namespaces and assembly name within the properties of your project, and check that, if you've added the project as a reference, that the path to the reference is consistent with the actual path. I have a strong feeling that there is some inconsistency somewhere if you've refactored this at any point and the code you think you are referencing isn't actually what is being referenced.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the issue myself and I spent a fair amount of time double and triple checking. This is not the issue, but thanks for your input @Caleb_McCreary

Comment: @JonahOberloh If you don't mind humoring me. If it would be safe to do, try completely removing the project in question and then use add existing to load it back into the solution. If you've already tried this and I overlooked it, I apologize.

Comment: This is useful advice.  I couldn't figure out the problem, everything looked right, then I finally noticed I'd created my new folder (and the files within it) within the bin directory.  It pays to very carefully check, because for me everything looked fine at first and second glance.